# How does one determine the amount of space allocated to their command line?

Tags: linux, shell, command, limit

How would one go about determining the amount of space allocated to their system for command lines. Is there anything else I need to be concerned with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### xargs

One method that I'm aware of is to use `xargs` to find this information out.

```
$ xargs --show-limits --no-run-if-empty < /dev/null 
Your environment variables take up 4791 bytes
POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system): 2090313
POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): 4096
Maximum length of command we could actually use: 2085522
Size of command buffer we are actually using: 131072
```

#### getconf

The limit that `xargs` is displaying derives from this system configuration value.

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX
2097152
```

Values such as these are typically "hard coded" on a system. See `man sysconf` for more on these types of values. I believe these types of values are accessible inside a C application, for example:

```
#include <unistd.h>
...
printf("%ld\n", sysconf(_SC_ARG_MAX));
```

#### References

- [ARG_MAX, maximum length of arguments for a new process](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/)